Structure of submodules of torsion module over pid.
It is from Jacobson's book Basic Algebra Vol.1, exercise 3.9.6.
In exercise 4, it is said:
Let $M$ be a torsion module for the p.i.d $D$ with invariant factor ideals $(d_1)\supset\cdots(d_s)$. Show that any homomorphic image $\bar{M}$ of $M$ is a torsion module with invariant factor ideals $(\bar{d_1})\supset\cdots(\bar{d_t})$ satisfying the conditions: $t\leq s$, $\bar{d_t}\mid d_s$,$\ldots$, $\bar{d_1}\mid d_{s-t+1}$. (Hint: Suppose first that $M$ is primary).
I show this by $\dim \frac{p^k M}{p^{k+1} M}\geq \dim \frac{p^k f(M)}{p^{k+1} f(M)}$.
But in exercise 6, it is said:
Show that the assertion made in exercise 4 on a homomorphic image $\bar{M}$ of M holds for any submodule $N$ of $M$.
I do not know how to do this. And I can not see why $\dim \frac{M}{p M}\geq \dim \frac{N}{p N}$.
Thanks in advance.

So just to clarify, your question is only how to solve exercise 6 then?

@MartinBrandenburg Yes. Because I'm not sure whether I have a misunderstanding, I tell the whole story.

I think I find an answer.
Let $M=\oplus_{i=1}^s Dz_i$ be a torsion module with $D\neq ann~z_i=(d_i)\neq 0$, $d_i|d_{i+1}$, and $N\leq M$ be a submodule.
Consider the homomorphism
$$\phi:D^s\to M$$
with $K=ker(\phi)$ and $L=\phi^{-1}(N)$. THen we have
$$M\cong D^s/K,\qquad N\cong L/K,\qquad M/N\cong D^s/L.$$
Let $f_i,e_j,g_k$ be basis of $K,D^s$ and $L$ respectively. Note that $K\leq L\leq D^s$, we have
$$f_i=\sum_j a_{ij}e_j,\qquad f_i=\sum_k b_{ik}g_k,\qquad g_k=\sum_j c_{kj}e_j.$$
As $f_i$ and $g_k$ are basis with $rank~K=rank~L=s$, we have
$$|A|,|B|,|C|\neq 0,\qquad A=BC.$$
The result on quotient modules concerns $C$ and $A$.
By taking the transpose, we have
(exercise 5, p194, Basic Algebra I) If $A$ and $B$ are matrix over $D$ with $det AB\neq 0$ and normal forms $diag(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $diag(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$, then $a_i|c_i$ and $b_i|c_i$ where $diag(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ is the normal form of $AB$.
By considering the invariant factors of $B$ and $A$, we have the result on submodules.

Sorry for being a little off topic. I see you are using the result of exercise 3.9.5. I have been trying to prove it for a couple of days but I am struggling to see the way. There are some question on this site about that, but they have no answers. Could you maybe help me with it?

By the way your observation on exercise 3.9.4 helped me a lot too.

@zinne98 The result on quotient module show the result of exercise 5 on $BC=A$ concering the invariant factors of $C$ and $A$. By taking a transpose, we just obtain the two sides of exercise 5. The way is to use exercise 4 to prove half of exercise 5, the other half is by taking transpose, which just solves exercise 6.

Thank you very much.
